# Resizing image from input file with Jimp

Tags: javascript, image, image-resizing

I want to resize the image which I get through input file. I found that [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)
seems to be a good option. The problem I have is that I don't know how to use it on the file. I tried to use this approach:

```
Jimp.read(lenna.buffer)
    .then(image => {
        // do stuff with the image
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // handle an exception
    });
```

Where `lenna` was my file, but I get an error:

```
No matching constructor overloading was found. 
Please see the docs for how to call the Jimp constructor.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541569/resize-image-with-javascript-and-save-to-disk

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using picture URL as I was displaying it on my website

Comment: That answer does not mention Jimp at all...? @ShaifulIslam

Answer (score -1):

maybe your file type is not supported, i think jimp only support png, jpg, bmp. Have a nice day!